# How export an imported NFS folder

Tags: nfs, mount-point

I need to export an imported NFS folder (called C) to a private cluster. That folder is being imported in my cluster server (called S) from a remote server (called A). In my cluster server, folder C is imported with no problems, but when I try to export that to my private cluster nodes, I receive this message from my cluster server (S): C does not support NFS export

Is there any way for exporting to my private nodes an imported NFS mount point?

All my systems are running CentOS-7-x86_64

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cant. This is called NFS re-export and it is not available with the standard NFS server (kernel module). You can try to nfs export it with userspace nfs server like ganesha.